# List files of a specific extension except one file using ls

Tags: bash, ls

In my dir, I have 'one.yaml', 'two.yaml', 'cron.yaml' and maybe lots of other yaml files. I'd like with ls (or another cmd if not possible) to select all the .yaml but cron.yaml

I tried `ls *.yaml -I cron.yaml` but it also returns cron.yaml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with the extended glob option. Use the syntax `!()` to match any pattern not inside the parenthesis.

```
shopt -s extglob 
ls -- !(cron).yaml
```

if this is just for listing and not meant to be used in a program, do this in a sub-shell to not make the glob option made permanent

```
(
    shopt -s extglob
    ls -- !(cron).yaml) ;
)
```

written in one line as `( shopt -s extglob; ls -- !(cron).yaml; )`.

POSIX shell does not support these extended glob options on which you could do

```
set -- *.yaml
for arg; do
    if [ "$arg" != "script.sh" ]; then 
        printf '%s\n' "$arg"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `ls -Ipattern` doesn't apply to files explicitly listed on the command line, as `cron.yaml` will be when you use `*.yaml`.

A quick way to do what you want would be to just use `grep -v`:

```
ls *.yaml | grep -v cron.yaml
```